# Trying to access a lazyily loaded model from another model in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two Hibernate Models like below

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table_a")
    public class A{
        private Integer p1;
        private B b;

        @Id
        @Column(name="id_a")
        public Integer getP1() {
            return p1;
        }

        public void setP1(Integer p1) {
            this.p1 = p1;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "t1")
        public B getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(B b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Transient
        public String getBVal(){
            if(b != null){
                return b.getT2();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and the other model B looks like this

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table_b")
    public class B{

        private int t1;
        private String t2;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "t1")
        public int getT1() {
            return t1;
        }

        public void setT1(int t1) {
            this.t1 = t1;
        }

        @Column(name = "t2")
        public String getT2() {
            return t2;
        }

        public void setT2(String t2) {
            this.t2 = t2;
        }
    }
```

the problem is when i use "getBVal" method of class A in my code it occasionally throws Nullpointer Exception which is strange to me
since i already have a null check in place in the corresponding transient method !
Any idea why is this npe coming and how can i avoid this ?

Thanks in Anticipation !

Comment: Can you share the log? Thank you!

Comment: Check your database integrity. It can happen when you point to non-existing id from another table.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the relatonship mapping of entity A to B.

Since B is not an attribute but a relationship, the correct way of mapping it would be as follows:

```
@OneToOne // Or @ManyToOne depending on your cardinality
@JoinColumn(name = "tx_b")
public B getB() {
    return b;
}
```

The default fetch type of the `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne` relationship mapping is `FetchType.EAGER`, which means that when you load the entity **A** the associated **B** entity will be loaded too.

I can't tell much more without seing the rest of your code (where you use the getBVal() method).

Comment: I have already defined @ManyToOne relationship in my entities.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the updated question when I posted my answer. Please, share the log and the place you are using the getBVal() method.